# BigQuery - Simba JDBC Connection Error Unrecognized character escape 'S'

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, simba

I am using Simba Big Query JDBC connector in a simple java application. I am using Google Service Account for user authentication. For OAuthPvtKeyPath, I am using the json key file.

My connection url looks like this "jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=;OAuthType=0;OAuthServiceAcctEmail=xxxxx@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com;OAuthPvtKeyPath="C:\xxx\xxxxx.json";";

Code:

```
'''
```

Connection connection = null;
com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.DataSource ds = new com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.DataSource();
ds.setURL(BIG_QUERY_CONNECTION_URL);
connection = ds.getConnection();

```
'''
```

The exception is raised at ds.getConnection () and looks like this.

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Simba]BigQueryJDBCDriver HttpTransport IO error : Unrecognized character escape 'S' (code 83)
at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 6].
at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.serviceAccountOAuth(Unknown Source)
at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.core.BQConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.AbstractDataSource.getSimbaConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.simba.googlebigquery.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba]BigQueryJDBCDriver HttpTransport IO error : Unrecognized character escape 'S' (code 83)
at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 6].
... 5 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized character escape 'S' (code 83)
at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2337)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:710)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._handleUnrecognizedCharacterEscape(ParserBase.java:1078)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._decodeEscaped(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3310)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishString2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2516)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishAndReturnString(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2471)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.getText(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:302)
at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonParser.getText(JacksonParser.java:74)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:856)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:360)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:335)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:79)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:73)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.fromStream(GoogleCredential.java:237)
at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.serviceAccountOAuth(Unknown Source)
at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.core.BQConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.AbstractDataSource.getSimbaConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)

Can you please help?

Regards,

Surjit

Answer (score 0):

OAuthType=4
ProjectId is missing